# Can protobuf-net serialize this combination of interface and generic collection?

Tags: generics, serialization, protobuf-net

I am trying to serialize a `ItemTransaction` and protobuf-net (r282) is having a problem.

```
ItemTransaction : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Type, IItemCollection>></code>
```

and ItemCollection is like this:

```
FooCollection : ItemCollection<Foo>
ItemCollection<T> : BindingList<T>, IItemCollection
IItemCollection : IList<Item>
```

where T is a derived type of Item. ItemCollection also has a property of type IItemCollection.

I am serializing like this:

```
IItemCollection itemCol = someService.Blah(...);
...
SerializeWithLengthPrefix<IItemCollection>(stream, itemCol, PrefixStyle.Base128);
```

My eventual goal is to serialize ItemTransaction, but am snagged with IItemCollection.

Item and it's derived types can be [de]serialized with no issues, see [1], but deserializing an IItemCollection fails (serializing works). ItemCollection has a ItemExpression property and when deserializing protobuf can't create an abstract class. This makes sense to me, but I'm not sure how to get through it.

```
ItemExpression<T> : ItemExpression, IItemExpression
ItemExpression : Expression
```

ItemExpression is abstract as is Expression

How do I get this to work properly?

Also, I am concerned that ItemTransaction will fail since the IItemCollections are going to be differing and unknown at compile time (an ItemTransaction will have FooCollection, BarCollection, FlimCollection, FlamCollection, etc).

What am I missing (Marc) ?

[1] [protobuf-net [de]serializing across assembly boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276104/protobuf-net-deserializing-across-assembly-boundaries)

Comment: For info, specific tests added and passing for "v2"; I haven't touched the (missing) with-length-prefix code, but getting there: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net.unittest/Meta/AbstractListsWithInheritance.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on the entire scenario; however `Merge` can be used to pass a concrete item in (in the case where you want to create an empty concrete instance yourself and let protobuf-net fill in the properties).

If the `ItemExpression` is decorated with `[ProtoInclude(...)]` for the expected `ItemExpression<T>` it *should* allow deserialization - abstract types are supported just as long as it never finds it needs to create one! See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678249/in-protobuf-net-how-can-i-pass-an-array-of-type-object-with-objects-of-different/2679154#2679154) which shows this in use.

If you can supply an example that I can use to reproduce the issue I should be able to provide more information.

---

Based on some off-forum examples, I think I've concluded that this *is* supported, but:

- if you just use `Deserialize...`, the outmost `IList<T>` derivative will be created by default as `List<T>`; you can get around this by using `Merge` instead, passing in a concrete list instance of your choosing to be filled
- all of `Item`, `Foo`, `Bar` should be marked as contract-types, with appropriate inheritance markers between `Item` and `Foo`, and `Item` and `Bar`
- in "v2" (soon) there is more control to manage concrete list types (and item types for untyped lists)
- there does seem to be a glitch related to list deserialization where the stated item type is not the root type. This looks to have been fixed automatically in "v2", but I need to chase it through (this unfortunately touches on the wrapper "WithLengthPrefix" / list outermost methods, which I'm still working on)
- in "v2" you can do the whole thing without needing the attributes if you like (although it still needs to be told how at some point)

But yes; it should work. I've e-mailed you a sample, and intend to tidy up the aforementioned outermost methods.

Comment: @tsupe - "Error 320", "The key you provided for file download was invalid."; you could try e-mailing me directly (see my profile page)

Comment: Thanks, Marc. I've emailed you.

Comment: Based on our emails and my investigation, protobuf-net v1 won't meet our needs at the moment and the current schedule and situation does not allow us to use non-production code. Thank you for your help.