# Serialize List<object> (where the objects are supported primitives) in Protobuf.NET?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

How to I serialize an object like this with protobuf-net:

```
public class MyObject{
   public string Key {get; set;}
   public List<Object> Values {get; set;}
}
```

When I try to serialize this with a TypeModel protobuf-net throws an error stating that it doesn't know how to serialize System.Object. Now I know that Values will only ever contain primitives (int, string, float, DateTime, etc.). So how do I let protobuf-net know about this?

Comment: It is, however, serializable.

Comment: I don't know protobuf but you're asking an awful lot from a serializer.

Comment: .NET DataContract serializes it just fine.... And yes, DateTime has a sort-of weird semi-primitive status in .NET. For instance, int? is valid and MyObject? is not, because MyObject is not a primitive, however DateTime? is perfectly valid. So no, perhaps not a primitive, but it's a value type, and it's built-in, and serializable.

Comment: Note that all `struct`s are a `ValueType` and since `int` is just `struct System.Int32`.... Consider the code `(42).GetType().BaseType` and `var v = new List<ValueType>() { 1, Guid.NewGuid() }`. However, this likely doesn't help with the problem at hand at all (it constrains the type to a `struct`, but not to a "supported serializable type") even though I find it interesting :) The "issue" is that protobuf-net only knows how to serialize/encode a very limited subset of types (whereas DCS and XmlSerializer are much more robust).

Comment: I think it may actually be a more fundamental issue: unless I am mistaken, protocol buffers only support homogenous lists..?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't really doable in pure ProtoBuf, in any sense. ProtoBuf is strongly typed, yet does not contain type information in the message; type information is always specified externally. Thus there are two "good" solutions; Ie, solutions which would be easy to interpret by a protobuf implementation other than Protobuf-net (Which you may or may not care about, but marc sure seems to).

1: Replace `List<object>` with `List<PrimitiveType>` where `PrimitiveType` contains optional fields corresponding to all the 12-or-so primitive types (Depending on your definition of "Primitive Type".), and you ensure only one of those is filled in on each instance.

2: Replace `List<object>` with a combination of `List<int>`, `List<double>`, `List<string>` etc.

Answer (score 1):

See [In Protobuf-net how can I pass an array of type object with objects of different types inside, knowing the set of potential types in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678249/in-protobuf-net-how-can-i-pass-an-array-of-type-object-with-objects-of-different).

As per Marc post (the author of Protobuf.NET) `object` is problematic. Although I can't find it right now, I distinctly remember seeing a check for `object` in the source to throw an exception against attempts to serialise object properties directly.

To work around this you should use a more specific class to be serialised and not use `object` directly. You can use `IProtoSerializer` to implement custom serialisation/deserialisation. Protobuf will also support `ISerializable` and `IXmlSerializable` interfaces if that helps.

Comment: To clarify: protobuf-net not not *consume* `ISerializable` nor `IXmlSerializable` - rather it can be used to *implement* them. `IProtoSerializer` is an *internal* class, and cannot be used in isolation.