# Protobuf-Net serialization of an array of objects with hierarchies

Tags: c#, arrays, serialization, protobuf-net

I am currently trying to serialize / deserialize (version 2.0.0.668) an array of objects where each object is a derrived type. The hierarchy, for simplicity, is as follows:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof (DeviceDescriptor1))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof (DeviceDescriptor1))]
public interface IDeviceDescriptor
{
}

[ProtoContract]
public sealed class DeviceDescriptor1
    : IDeviceDescriptor
{
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public sealed class DeviceDescriptor2
    : IDeviceDescriptor
{
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

The following test code first serializes an array, then deserializes it again:

```
var devices = new IDeviceDescriptor[]
{
    new DeviceDescriptor1{Foo = 1},
    new DeviceDescriptor2{Bar=42},
};

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Serializer.Serialize(stream, devices);
    stream.Position = 0;
    var actualDevices = Serializer.Deserialize<IDeviceDescriptor[]>(stream);
}
```

However upon deserialization, a ProtoException is thrown: *The type cannot be changed once a serializer has been generated for ProtoBuf.DeviceDescriptor1 (ProtoBuf.IDeviceDescriptor)*

I stumbled upon an older question of similar nature ([In Protobuf-net how can I pass an array of type object with objects of different types inside, knowing the set of potential types in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678249/in-protobuf-net-how-can-i-pass-an-array-of-type-object-with-objects-of-different)), but I am unsure if this one still applies - nearly 4 years later.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Is this case unsupported? If so, what are my options to solve this particular problem?

Any help is appreciated :)

*edit*

This is the workaround for this particular problem that I came up with: Instead of serializing an array of abstract types, I serialize a generic type 'ProtobufFrame' (with one field of type T) which in this particular case ends up being 'ProtobufFrame'.